# Publicando pacotes no repositório NPM

Tags: git, npm

Como publicar um pacote feito por mim no repositório do npm para outros programadores testarem ?

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada aqui na documentação... https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#how-to-publish--update-a-package), estes são os passos:

1. [Crie](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#create-a-user-account) uma conta no NPM
2. Revise o código

   1. [Revise os arquivos](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#review-the-contents) que precisam ser enviados
   2. [Veja se seu package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#review-the-packagejson-file) segue os padrões adequados
   3. Escolha um [nome único](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#choose-a-name) para o seu pacote
   4. [Inclua documentação](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#include-documentation-readmemd) no README.md
3. [Publique](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#publish)!
4. [Teste](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#test)